# need help converting label to string to output in another label box for summary: C#

Tags: c#

```
strFirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
strLastName = txtLastName.Text;

lblSummary = "FirstName:" + strFirstName + Environment.NewLine +
   "Last Name:" + strLastName + Environment.NewLine +
   "Gross Income:" + decGrossIncome.ToString("c") + Environment.NewLine +
   "Taxes Due:" + decTaxesDue.ToString("c") + Environment.NewLine +
   "Total Payments:" + decTotalPayments.ToString("c") + Environment.NewLine +
   "Total Amount Due:" + decTotalAmountDue.ToString("c");


lblSummary.Text = strSummary;
```

***note***the following contains the error

```
"Total Amount Due:" + decTotalAmountDue.ToString("c");
```

The error I get is:

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' E:\CIS 162 AD\CS03\CS03\CS03\Form1.cs 79 37 CS03

Comment: @jeffrey would pls specify the error message that you have got...

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' E:\CIS 162 AD\CS03\CS03\CS03\Form1.cs 79 37 CS03

Comment: @JeffreyOrris: Exactly - look at the type of the expression on the right hand side. Now look at the type of the variable you're trying to assign the value to...

Comment: the "total Amount Due" is from a label everything else is from text boxes

Comment: never mind everything else was also labels...but how come i dont get error messages from the other statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assign a *string* value straight to a `Label` variable. I suspect you meant this:

```
string strSummary = "FirstName:" + strFirstName + Environment.NewLine +
    "Last Name:" + strLastName + Environment.NewLine +
    "Gross Income:" + decGrossIncome.ToString("c") + Environment.NewLine +
    "Taxes Due:" + decTaxesDue.ToString("c") + Environment.NewLine +
    "Total Payments:" + decTotalPayments.ToString("c") + Environment.NewLine +
    "Total Amount Due:" + decTotalAmountDue.ToString("c");

lblSummary.Text = strSummary;
```

I would personally advise using `string.Format`, and ditching the pseudo-Hungarian naming by the way.

```
string summary = string.Format("First Name: {1}{0}" + 
                               "Last Name: {2}{0}" +
                               "Gross Income: {3:c}{0}" +
                               "Taxes Due: {4:c}{0}" +
                               "Total Payments: {5:c}{0}" +
                               "Total Amount Due: {6:c}",
                               Environment.NewLine, firstName, lastName,
                               grossIncome, taxesDue, totalPayments,
                               totalAmountDue);

// I'm not so hot on naming controls, so I'm not saying this is great - but I
// prefer it not to be control-type-specific; what's important is that it's a
// control we're using to output the summary.
summaryOutput.Text = summary;
```

Comment: +1 for knowing that's not real Hungarian notation...